# A generating subset of a vector space contains a basis

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a vector space having dimension $n$, and let $S$ be a subset of $V$ that generates $V$.

Prove that there is a subset of $S$ that is a basis for $V$. (Be careful not to assume that $S$ is finite.)

I can prove this if S is finite, but it says not to assume that S is finite..  How to prove this? Please help.. T.T

Comment: Zorns' lemma? ${}{}{}$

Comment: No.it's not related to Zorns' lemma.T.T

Comment: "If V has dimension n, then S must be finite." Is this some theorem? Or is it just a trivial statement?

Answer (score 1):

Reduce the problem to one where $S$ is finite.

Since $\dim V = n$, there is a basis of cardinality $n$. Hence we have $V = \operatorname{sp}\{b_k\}_{k=1}^n = \operatorname{sp} S$, for some collection of vectors $b_k$.

Hence each $b_k$ can be written as a finite linear combination of elements of $S$, say $b_k = \sum_{i=1}^{n_k} \alpha_i^k s_i^k$.

If we let $S' = \{s_i^k \}_{i,k}$, then $S'$ is a finite subset of $S$ that generates $V$.

Comment: Thank you! Can I ask just one more question? bk is an arbitrary element in span(S)? And does ' spS ' mean spanS?

Comment: Yes, the $\operatorname{sp}$ is the span. If $V$ has dimension $n$ this means there is a basis of cardinality $n$, so take the $b_k$ to be such a basis.

Comment: Now I got it!! Thank you for helping me !! :)